# How do I clear the HTML of the first child for an array of elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here's what I've got so far. `srm`, `sre`, `srd` are all jQuery objects. I want to clear the HTML out of the first child of each object. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but this is what I have so far.

```
$([srm,sre,srd]).children(":first-child").html('');
```

Nothing really happens so I'm assuming that this is incorrect somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
$.each([srm,sre,srd], function(index, element) {
  element.children(":first-child").html('');
});
```

*(And have a look at [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) as @Nick suggests)*

Comment: +1 - I would use `.empty()` here which cleans up better, but this is the right looping approach.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Ah I knew there was a method that clears the content :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$([srm,sre,srd]).children(":first").html('');
```

Comment: From the docs: *While `:first` matches only a **single element**, the `:first-child` selector can match more than one: one for each parent.*